# How to get the phone number from a vcard

Tags: java, mobile, netbeans, io, libraries

I am using cardme library to deal with vcards. Following is my code

```
package vcardtest;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.sourceforge.cardme.engine.VCardEngine;
import net.sourceforge.cardme.vcard.VCard;
import net.sourceforge.cardme.vcard.features.EmailFeature;
import net.sourceforge.cardme.vcard.features.NameFeature;
import net.sourceforge.cardme.vcard.features.NicknameFeature;
import net.sourceforge.cardme.vcard.features.TelephoneFeature;
import net.sourceforge.cardme.vcard.types.parameters.TelephoneParameterType;

public class VCardTest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        File vcardFile = new File("C:/Users/yohan/Contacts/Yohan Weerasinghe.vcf");
        VCardEngine vcardEngine = new VCardEngine();
        try 
        {
            VCard vcard = vcardEngine.parse(vcardFile);
            String name = vcard.getName().getGivenName();

            EmailFeature email = vcard.getEmails().next();
            String sEmail = email.getEmail();

            NicknameFeature nickName = vcard.getNicknames();
            Iterator<String> nicknames = nickName.getNicknames();
            String sNickName = nicknames.next();

            Iterator<TelephoneFeature> telephoneNumbers = vcard.getTelephoneNumbers();
            TelephoneFeature next = telephoneNumbers.next();

            String telephone = "";


                while(vcard.getTelephoneNumbers().hasNext())
                {
                    TelephoneFeature next1 = vcard.getTelephoneNumbers().next();
                    telephone = next1.getTelephone();



                    System.out.println(telephone);
                }



            Iterator<TelephoneParameterType> telephoneParameterTypes = next.getTelephoneParameterTypes();
            TelephoneParameterType next1 = telephoneParameterTypes.next();
            String type = next1.getType();

            TelephoneParameterType next2 = telephoneParameterTypes.next();
            String type2 = next2.getType();


            System.out.println( name );
            System.out.println(sEmail);
            System.out.println(sNickName);

            System.out.println(type);
            System.out.println(type2);


        } catch (IOException ex) 
        {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, there is no method called getNumber() or something. How can I get the mobile numbers and land numbers? Please help!

NOTE: I UPDATED THE CODE. In there, you can see I managed to get the phone number. But, this returns only the HOME phone and not anything else. Even the loop is not stopping. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see

```
TelephoneFeature.getTelephone()
```

I'd also suggest taking a look at

```
TelephoneFeature.getTelephoneParameterTypes()
```

to see the types

**UPDATE**

Be careful with the iterators

Each call to vcard.getTelephoneNumbers() is creating a new `Iterator`, which means you could end up in an infinite loop.

```
Iterator<TelephoneFeature> itNumbers = vcard.getTelephoneNumbers();
while (itNumbers.hasNext()) {

    TelephoneFeature next1 = itNumbers.next();
    String telephone = next1.getTelephone();

    System.out.println(telephone);
    System.out.println("types = " + next1.getExtendedTelephoneParameterSize());

    Iterator<XTelephoneParameterType> itTypes = next1.getExtendedTelephoneParameterTypes();
    while (itTypes.hasNext()) {

        XTelephoneParameterType next = itTypes.next();
        System.out.println(" - " + next.getType() + " / " + next.getDescription());

    }

}
```

I stand corrected, the problem (isn't a bug) it's with the tester, not the API :P

If you add

```
Iterator<TelephoneParameterType> itNTypes = next1.getTelephoneParameterTypes();
while (itNTypes .hasNext()) {

    TelephoneParameterType next = itNTypes .next();
    System.out.println(" - " + next.getType() + " / " + next.getDescription());

}
```

to the previous loop, you should get what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Give me 30 mins to check this out :)

Comment: Please be kind enough to help me in here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153852/unable-to-read-vcards-with-address