# Unable to read vcards with address

Tags: java, mobile, netbeans, io, libraries

Please have a look at the following code

```
package vcardtest;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.sourceforge.cardme.engine.VCardEngine;
import net.sourceforge.cardme.vcard.VCard;
import net.sourceforge.cardme.vcard.features.*;
import net.sourceforge.cardme.vcard.types.parameters.TelephoneParameterType;
import net.sourceforge.cardme.vcard.types.parameters.XTelephoneParameterType;

public class VCardTest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        File vcardFile = new File("C:/Users/yohan/Contacts/Akon Kon.vcf");
        VCardEngine vcardEngine = new VCardEngine();
        try 
        {
            VCard vcard = vcardEngine.parse(vcardFile);
            String name = vcard.getName().getGivenName();

            if(vcard.hasEmails())
            {
                 EmailFeature email = vcard.getEmails().next();
                String sEmail = email.getEmail();
                   System.out.println(sEmail);
            }


            if(vcard.hasNicknames())
            {
            NicknameFeature nickName = vcard.getNicknames();
            Iterator<String> nicknames = nickName.getNicknames();
            String sNickName = nicknames.next();  
             System.out.println(sNickName);
            }


           // if(vcard.hasAddresses())
            //{
            //Iterator<AddressFeature> addresses = vcard.getAddresses();
            //AddressFeature address = addresses.next();
            //String streetAddress = address.getStreetAddress();
            //System.out.println(streetAddress);
            //}
            String telephone = "";


            //Getting the phone numbers

            Iterator<TelephoneFeature> itNumbers = vcard.getTelephoneNumbers();

            while (itNumbers.hasNext()) 
            {

                TelephoneFeature next1 = itNumbers.next();
                telephone = next1.getTelephone();

           //     System.out.println(telephone);
                System.out.println("types = " + next1.getExtendedTelephoneParameterSize());

                Iterator<XTelephoneParameterType> itTypes = next1.getExtendedTelephoneParameterTypes();

                Iterator<TelephoneParameterType> itNTypes = next1.getTelephoneParameterTypes();

                while (itNTypes .hasNext()) 
                {

                        TelephoneParameterType next = itNTypes .next();
                        System.out.println(" - " + next.getType() + " / " + next.getDescription());

                        if(next.getType().equals("CELL"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Cell Phone Number: " + next1.getTelephone());
                        }
                        else if(next.getType().equals("HOME"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Home Number is: " + next1.getTelephone());
                        }

                }

            }



            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println( name );


            //System.out.println(streetAddress);



        } catch (IOException ex) 
        {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I pass a VCard with an address, this generates the following error

> run: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/codec/net/QuotedPrintableCodec     at
>   net.sourceforge.cardme.engine.VCardEngine.parseLabelType(VCardEngine.java:1432)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.cardme.engine.VCardEngine.parseLine(VCardEngine.java:523)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.cardme.engine.VCardEngine.parseVCard(VCardEngine.java:348)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.cardme.engine.VCardEngine.parse(VCardEngine.java:254)
>     at vcardtest.VCardTest.main(VCardTest.java:22) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCodec     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)     ... 5 more Java
>   Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Following the test VCard I used, which is generated by my phone, send to laptop and got converted to .contact, and manually converted back to .vcf using options in the contacts folder of windows.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Kon;Akon
FN:Akon Kon
TEL;CELL;VOICE:0711111111
ADR;HOME:;;195;Colj;Sri lanka
LABEL;HOME;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:195=0D=0AColj, Sri lanka
EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:akok@a.com
REV:20120828T061900Z
END:VCARD
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to missing the [Apache Commons Codec library](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)

You'll need to download it & its dependencies & add them to your class path